# Add list item from consol C#

Tags: c#, list

I´m making a very simple Hangman game and using 2 files. Program.cs and WordList.cs.

The menu is:

1. Add words
2. Show list off words
3. Play
4. Exit

I´m wondering how to get a word written in the consol to go into the list of words. So if I choose menu item 1, I should be able to enter a maximum off 5 words and make them go into the word list.
Really hope someone can help as I´m a little lost. Need I say beginner at C#:) I haven´t figured out how the program searches each letter yet, but dealing with this problem first...

Here is the code in program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class Hangman
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Title = "C# Hangman";
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome To C# Hangman!");

        //MENU

        char MenuChoice;       

        Console.Write("\n\t1) Add words");
        Console.Write("\n\t2) Show list of words");
        Console.Write("\n\t3) Play");
        Console.Write("\n\t4) Quit\n\n");

        Console.Write("\n\tChoose 1-4: ");        //Choose meny item
        MenuChoice = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (MenuChoice)
            {
                case '1':

                    break;
                case '2':
                    WordList showing = new WordList();
                    showing.ListOfWords();
                    Console.Write("\n\tList of words\n\n");


                    break;


                case '3':   //Running game

                    int guesses;
                    Console.Write("\n\tHow many faults can you have: ");
                    guesses = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("\n\tAwesome, let´s play!\n");


                    String input;
                    bool wrong;
                    int NumberOfTries = 0;


                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tWrong guesses: " + NumberOfTries + " / " + guesses + "\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tGuessed letters:\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tWord:\n");
                        Console.Write("\n\n\tGuess letter: ");
                        input = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("\n\n\t ");

                        wrong = !input.Equals("t") &&
                              !input.Equals("e") &&
                              !input.Equals("s") &&
                              !input.Equals("t"); 
                        if (wrong)
                        {
                            NumberOfTries++;
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\tWrong letter " + "Try again!");
                        }
                        if (wrong && (NumberOfTries > guesses - 1))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\tYou have failed " + guesses + ". End of game!\n");
                            break;
                        }

                    } while (wrong);
                    if (!wrong)
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tWhohoo!");

                    break;

                case '4':

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tEnd game?\n\n");
                    break;
            }

    }

}
```

And here is the code in WordList.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class WordList
{
    public void ListOfWords()
    {

        List<string> words = new List<string>(); // List

        words.Add("test");         // Contains: test
        words.Add("dog");          // Contains: test, dog
        words.Insert(1, "shit"); // Contains: test, shit, dog

        words.Sort();
        foreach (string word in words) // Display for verification
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);

        }

}
}
```

Comment: `C` has no relation to `Visual C#`. In the future you should refrain from using the `C` tag when asking a question with regards to `C#` :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend your app like this with moving your showing declaration outside of your switch

```
var showing = new WordList();
switch (MenuChoice)
        {
            case '1':
                showing.AddWord(Console.ReadLine())
                break;
            case '2':
                showing = new WordList();
                showing.ListOfWords();
                Console.Write("\n\tList of words\n\n");
```

And extend your Wordlist to keep your words and add a method to add new words

```
class WordList
{
   private words = new List<string>();
   'keep the constructor but move declaration

   public void AddWord(string word)
   {

    words.Add(word);
   }
```

In fact with some refactoring you can keep remove the class wordlist and just keep the list in your Program.cs, but it really could use more then that as refactoring

I'll try and modify your code in total (don't got a compiler right now so don't blame any minor syntax issues (using VB.net normally)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class Hangman
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Title = "C# Hangman";
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome To C# Hangman!");

        //MENU

        char MenuChoice;       

        Console.Write("\n\t1) Add words");
        Console.Write("\n\t2) Show list of words");
        Console.Write("\n\t3) Play");
        Console.Write("\n\t4) Quit\n\n");

        Console.Write("\n\tChoose 1-4: ");        //Choose meny item
        MenuChoice = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        WordList showing = new WordList();
            switch (MenuChoice)
            {
                case '1':
                    var input = Console.ReadLine();
                    showing.AddWord(input);
                    break;
                case '2':

                    showing.ListOfWords();
                    Console.Write("\n\tList of words\n\n");


                    break;


                case '3':   //Running game

                    int guesses;
                    Console.Write("\n\tHow many faults can you have: ");
                    guesses = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("\n\tAwesome, let´s play!\n");


                    String input;
                    bool wrong;
                    int NumberOfTries = 0;


                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tWrong guesses: " + NumberOfTries + " / " + guesses + "\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tGuessed letters:\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tWord:\n");
                        Console.Write("\n\n\tGuess letter: ");
                        input = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("\n\n\t ");

                        wrong = !input.Equals("t") &&
                              !input.Equals("e") &&
                              !input.Equals("s") &&
                              !input.Equals("t"); 
                        if (wrong)
                        {
                            NumberOfTries++;
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\tWrong letter " + "Try again!");
                        }
                        if (wrong && (NumberOfTries > guesses - 1))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\tYou have failed " + guesses + ". End of game!\n");
                            break;
                        }

                    } while (wrong);
                    if (!wrong)
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tWhohoo!");

                    break;

                case '4':

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tEnd game?\n\n");
                    break;
            }

    }

}
```

And here is the code in WordList.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class WordList
{
    private List<string> words = new List<string>();

    public void ListOfWords()
    {
        words.Add("test");         // Contains: test
        words.Add("dog");          // Contains: test, dog
        words.Insert(1, "shit"); // Contains: test, shit, dog

        words.Sort();
        foreach (string word in words) // Display for verification
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);

        }

    }

    public void AddWord(string value){
        words.Add(value);
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi,I just tried it but can´t get it to work. Just gets a bunch of error messages:(

Comment: I added the code in total, you can try if it's ok this way, don't got a compiler right now

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out. I just tried again and it´s still alot of errors. The first one is saying invalid token '=' in private words = new List<string>(); on the WordList.cs file.

Comment: change input on my changes to another word, it will run. But still needs some work

Comment: I changed input to something else and also the "private words = new List<string>(); to List <string> words = new List<string>(); and the errors are gone but I´m not sure if it´s working. Where goes the words I´m entering?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Console.ReadLine()`

```
        string word = "";
        while (word != null && !word.Equals("DONE"))
        {
            word = Console.ReadLine();
            wordList.Add(word);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it´only prints out the word, it doen´t go into the list...

Comment: Isn't there an Add method (or an equivalent) on WordList

Comment: But what if the user wants to add `"DONE"` to the list of words? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You've got a collection of words.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

You read from the console the word

```
var inputString = Console.ReadLine();
```

You could trim it if you like

```
inputString = inputString.Trim();  // that'll remove the spaces on the front/back of the string
```

Then you can add it to the list

```
myList.Add(inputString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since words are separated by spaces, you can have the user enter their list of words like this:
`these are four words`, which you can read easily with

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
// input == "these are four words"
```

Creating the list is now very simple

```
string[] words1 = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, // Splits the words by space
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// words1 = { "these", "are", "four", "words" }
```

If you absolutely need a `List<string>`, you just need to add `.ToList()` at the end:

```
List<string> words2 = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Where exactly should I write this code?

Comment: @Karolina Erm... You write the code wherever you need it to be executed, of course. The `ReadLine` is usually used, whenever you expect the user to write something in the console, whereas `Split` can be used anywhere, as soon as `input` is set. Just make sure you declare your `string[]` or `List<string>` in the right scope.

Comment: Sorry I´m a total rookie:( I tried to put string input = Console.ReadLine(); under switch option 1 but should I don´t know where to use the rest. Which of the files? I get an error message "A local variable named isput is already defined in this scope. I used it further down...

Comment: @Karolina I see you don't understand what a scope is. The easiest way to detect a scope, is by looking for curly brackets `{ }`. Whenever you declare a variable (e.g. `string input`) inside curly brackets, the variable exists only within those (and also within any brackets nested inside). Now there's a naughty little trap: The scope is not limited to whatever is *below*, but also extends to what is *above*. That's the error you're getting. The easiest fix, is by changing the name of your variable: `string inputWords = Console.ReadLine(); string[] words = inputWords.Split(...` for example.